# How to define a general method / catch it all method for an object?

Tags: php, object, php-5.4, magic-function

On the same concept for object members, I can define generic __get and __set.
How do I do the same for methods?

```
class a{
  public method __general(){
  }


  public function b(){}
}

$r= new a();
$r->b(); //will use existing method
$r->baba()//will call __general()
$r->p()//will call __general()
```

You r more than welcome editing my language, if u understand what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `__call` or `__callStatic` magic methods.

Check out [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)